# How to migrate model with ClassicWithBackgroundCoordinatorSQLiteMagicalRecordStack on MagicalRecord 3.0?

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

I'm using MagicalRecord 3.0's `ClassicWithBackgroundCoordinatorSQLiteMagicalRecordStack` stack, which allows for the creation of two persistent store coordinators and a single physical store. It works well and I'm quite happy with it.

I now need to migrate my data model. I versioned my model, but the migration is not triggered and the app crashes (unless I delete the app and reinstall fresh).

The change is minor and should be a lightweight migration. How can I trigger an appropriate migration in this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, there isn't an API for that case just yet. Please open an issue on github. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much. I opened an issue on github. If you have any suggestions on how I might address this manually in the interim I'd be very appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: Any news on this?  I have the same issue.